# Parallel Computing with OpenMP or _gnu_parallel does not speed up the code

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I have this piece of code. I am trying to apply OpenMP, `__gnu_parallel::for_each` as well  to make it parallel, but none of the methods are working.

What should I do? 
Here make is a vector of sets and the type contained in the set is `OctCell*`.

The algorithm gives the correct output, but does not speed up the code. I have 4 cores.

```
void Oct :: applyFunction3(void (*Function)(OctCell* cell), unsigned int level)
{
    __gnu_parallel::for_each(make.at(level).begin(),make.at(level).end(),Function);
}
```

The Function is

```
void directionalSweepX(OctCell* cell) {
OctCell* positiveCell,*negativeCell;
     positiveCell = cell->getNeighbour(RIGHT);
   negativeCell = cell->getNeighbour(LEFT);
    addFluxToConserveds(cell, positiveCell, negativeCell, X);
}
```

The addFluxtoConserveds does the following

```
void addFluxToConserveds(OctCell* cell, OctCell* positiveCell, OctCell* negativeCell, SWEEP_DIRECTION direction) {

    double deltaT = pow(2.0, cell->getLevel() - cell->getParentOct()->lMin)*gDeltaT;
    // You have corrected that delta t is delta (L)
    double alpha = (1 << (int) cell->getParentOct()->lMin) * gDeltaT/gL;// whats the purpose f <<

    double beta = alpha/8.0;
    double gamma;
    double Flux[5] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};

    if ( positiveCell == 0) {
        Flux[direction+1] = getPressure(cell);
    } else if ( positiveCell->isLeaf() ) {
        computeFlux(cell, positiveCell, direction, Flux);
        gamma = (positiveCell->getLevel() == cell->getLevel())  ? alpha : beta;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        cell->mConserveds_n[i] -= alpha * Flux[i];
        if (positiveCell) positiveCell->mConserveds_n[i] += gamma * Flux[i];
    }

    Flux[0] = Flux[1] = Flux[2] = Flux[3] = Flux[4] = 0.0;

    if ( negativeCell == 0 ) {
        Flux[direction+1] = getPressure(cell);
    } else if (negativeCell->isLeaf() && negativeCell->getLevel() == cell->getLevel() - 1 ) {
        computeFlux(negativeCell, cell, direction, Flux);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        cell->mConserveds_n[i] += alpha * Flux[i];
        if (negativeCell) negativeCell->mConserveds_n[i] -= beta * Flux[i];
   }

}
```

Comment: The function operates on an octcell, given its pointer.

Comment: Right, but what does it do? (It may just not be an operation that parallelizes very well.)

Comment: void directionalSweepX(OctCell* cell) {
OctCell* positiveCell,*negativeCell;
     positiveCell = cell->getNeighbour(RIGHT);
   negativeCell = cell->getNeighbour(LEFT);
    addFluxToConserveds(cell, positiveCell, negativeCell, X);
}

Comment: How many `OctCell`s are in your vector? if its very few, the overhead of distributing the tasks to threads is probably canceling out your parallel computation gain.

Comment: I have added the functions. The number of Octcells are say 2,00,000.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Could you figure out the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `#include <omp.h>`.

In the function `addFluxtoConserveds` you can add a `#pragma omp for` to the two for loops. This is because each iteration does not depend on the others to complete.
Because you have a secquential code that important to the second for loop, you can't work with `sections` or `tasks` in here.

What is the sequential implementation of `applyFunction3` ?

You have to remember one **critical** thing about OpenMP. A program compiled on an architecture does not become optimized for every other architecture, even in the same family of processors (intel core duo vs intel dual core; intel vs amd; etc.). 
This means it runs fast on the original architecture it was compiled and on the other ones it's just luck.

Comment: But the parallel thing is not working for the two loops....its not speeding up at all.

Comment: What do i do now ? Can you give me your mail id?

Comment: there are 5 iterations with simple operations in them. They will execute extremely fast which means in this case you should see if the the thread overhead is not worse then sequential for. But besides personal observation, how do you measure the speed of the algorithm ? (what is the code)

Comment: Applying pragma to that portion is making the code even slower

Comment: and again, what is the purpose of `applyFunction3` and how is `computeflux` implemented ?

Comment: this means the overhead is too big for the speed of operations.

Comment: applyFunction3 send the octcell for which flux is computed in the computeFlux

Comment: and what is the sequential code of applyFunction3 ? Also what is the function that takes the most time to complete ?

Comment: The apply Function is being called for a large number of cells, for which Flux is computed for each cell. The calculation of flux is thus being called a large number of times and it involves some calculation,

Comment: In case the left and right fluxes can be parallelized, i need to put in all the variales as private, But there are a large number of variables. WHat do i do?

Comment: `addFluxToConserveds` and `directionalSweepX` are executed fast so you will only ruin the speed if you parallelise inside of them. The function that can be put in a parallel for is the `applyFunction` but I still need to see how it is implemented in the sequential mode si I can figure it out how to make it fast using parallelism. So add the sequential code for `applyFunction`.